# Retrofit2 & Rxjava2 How To Get The Url In The Method OnError(Throwable e)

Tags: android, retrofit2

I've recently started using Rxjava2 and Retrofit2 ,Then I wanna find a way to create the unified callback for the method onNext(Response t)  and onError(Throwable e).
I can get the Url in onNext(Response t) by `t.response().raw().request().url()`. But I cant find the same way in onError(Throwable e). So wat should i do?

Comment: can you please explain your requirements properly. what I can understand is that you need a single observer for handling all retrofit calls?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can only get that if the `throwable` is a `HttpException`, which only happens if the call returned a status other than 2XX.

In this case, you can get the response from the throwable and from there the url.

Here's one way to do that:

```
void onError(Throwable throwable) {
   if( throwable instanceof HttpException) {
     HttpUrl url = ((HttpException) throwable)
                       .response()
                       .raw()
                       .request()
                       .url();
     // ...
   }
     // ...
 }
```

Here's info about the [HttpException](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/HttpException.html)